# Current best practices for Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I code on the side, and I pulled out some old websites I built with a friend to get working again.  I haven't done any AJAX for a while and as I try to figure out where my code is failing, I am finding that there are not a lot of resources showing up.  I am guessing that it is because I am using old methods.  I am trying to see if there is a quick change to my approach I should consider, or whether somebody knows a way to work with what I have to find the problem.  These webpages use jQuery 1.4.4, so quite old.

Here is my old code:

```
var ajaxRequest = getAjaxRequest();
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "none"; },2000);
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "url.php" + encodeURIComponent(appleObject), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

I am seeing a lot of code more like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url.php",
    success: function(something){
        something
    }
});
```

My goal is to use the "success" or "onSuccess" to make sure the page was found and console.log something returned from the php file if possible.

Questions:
-Is my method a security problem, needing major update?
-If so, am I just going to need to bite the bullet and update jQuery, too?
-If not, can somebody suggest how I can do some form of "success" call using my existing code?  i.e. something like:  `ajaxRequest.success(console.log(something));`

Comment: The "old" code does not appear to use JQuery to do the AJAX request at all, while the second chunk of code does. The original code only needs an additional `if(ajaxRequest.status === 200)` nested within the first `if` and it will be fine.

Comment: The old code looks fine. The 'new' is just the (easier to code) jQuery version.

Comment: @Jeff Checking the `readyState` for `4` only tells you if you got a response. You still need to check `xhr.status === 200` to know that it is a good response.

Comment: @ScottMarcus true... edited my comment

Comment: So, the style changes occur only after success?  Such that if I see those style changes I know it found the php file?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The code in the `true` section of the `if` statement only runs if the request returns (but you do have to add the additional `if` check I mentioned above).

Comment: So, `ajaxRequest.readyState == 4` just makes sure it found the php file?  And `ajaxRequest.status === 200` would make sure that the php code successfully ran?

Comment: Well, `readyState === 4` means that the request was made and a response was returned. But, you don't know what the response was. That's why you need the second test for `.status === 200`, which means the response was `OK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old code does not use JQuery to do the AJAX call, so whatever the 1.4 version was in there for, it wasn't for AJAX.

Your question really boils down to whether or not to use JQuery for this task. JQuery is nothing more than a JavaScript library that makes many tasks simpler to write. There is absolutely nothing that JQuery can do that you can't do without it because JQuery ***is*** JavaScript. If you were to use JQuery, then behind the scenes, JQuery would just be doing what your original code already did.

Your original code already has a "success" section, it's just not labelled that specifically. But, it does lack a second test for the `request.status === 200` to know that the response from the request was a good one (200 is the HTTP status code for `OK`).

So, the original code should really have been this:

```
var ajaxRequest = getAjaxRequest();
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
      // Response received...
      if(ajaxRequest.status === 200){
        // Request was successful - returned data (if any)
        // is available via the xhr.responseText property
        document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){ 
         document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "none"; 
        },2000);
      }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "url.php" + encodeURIComponent(appleObject), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

But, you can modernize the syntax here a bit to make it a bit more intuitive:

```
var ajaxRequest = getAjaxRequest();
ajaxRequest.addEventListener("load", function(data){
  // Request was successful - returned data (if any)
  // is available via the xhr.responseText property
  document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "none"; 
    },2000);
});

ajaxRequest.addEventListener("error", function(evt){
  // Request was unsuccessful
  console.log("ERROR", evt)
});

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "url.php" + encodeURIComponent(appleObject), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

You can read about **[making XMLHttpRequests here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)**.

Comment: The other question here, is with what is returned from PHP.  If I echo something in PHP and then want it to appear in the console, does that come back in the "evt" or do I need some other way to catch that returned string?

Comment: @Thomas As my comments state, the returned data will be available in the `.responseText` property of the AJAX component.

Comment: Okay, I found that in the linked documentation, thanks.  I am using `console.log(this.responseText);` and seeing what I needed.  Perfect.